# Haskell multidimensional list : Beginner problems

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, multidimensional-array

I want to delete every string in a list which starts with "h".

> ["hawrw", "basw", "HasD" , "hgkas"]  =>  ["basw", "HasD"]

My code is:

```
kat (x:xs) = if head x == "h" then kat(xs) else x ++ kat(xs)
```

Why doesn't it work? And how can I fix my code?

Comment: define "doesn't work"

Comment: <interactive>:1:4:
    Couldn't match expected type `[[[Char]]]'
                with actual type `(t0, t1)'
    In the first argument of `kat', namely `("abc", "hef")'
    In the expression: kat ("abc", "hef")
    In an equation for `it': it = kat ("abc", "hef")

That is the error I get.

I just want to check the first Element of each String whether it is == "h" or not. 
If it is == "h" then I just take the rest of the list and put it into my function
If it is not == "h" then I want to keep the first string and apply my function on the rest of the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You need a base case: `kat [] = []`
- `"h"` is a string, you want to compare to a character, use: `'h'`
- `++` is string concatenation, you want to create a list, replace it with `:`.

Notes:

- `head` is not safe, and will fail with an empty `""` string. You can test this with `null x`.
- The idiomatic way would be to use `filter`, because you're really filtering.
- Use type signatures to detect errors early and get more meaningful error messages.

Comment: Thanks I am new to functional programming.

Answer (score 2):

`filterList = filter (\x -> head x /= 'h')`

Your code doesn't work beause the head of a `String` is not a `String`.  It is a `Char` when you use `"h"` you mean a `String` with only one element.

Answer (score 2):

Of course the filter solution by Diego is the preferred "real-world" style, but if you want to fix your example, why not using more pattern matching? After all, Strings are just lists.

```
kat (('h':_):xs) = kat xs
kat (x:xs) = x : kat xs
kat [] = []
```

Another nice way is to employ list comprehensions:

```
kat xs = [ys | ys@(y:_) <- xs, y /= 'h']
```